# Redirection in Servlet causing erroneous loading of remote resources

Tags: servlets, tomcat7

I'm developing a Java EE application using web services to communicate with distant server.

To avoid Cross-origin resource sharing(CORS) problems I use a bridge Servlet to redirect and filter the requests.

However, when some distant pages are loaded the CSS and Javascript files located at this distant server will get their absolute path transformed and their root folder becomes the root of the local Web Application.

This is a chunk of HTML code of a distant web page called by the web application:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/analytics/res/b_mozilla/browserdom.js">
</script>
```

**src="/analytics/res/b_mozilla/browserdom.js"** is located at `http://remotehost:9704`
but when it's loaded the path becomes `http://localhost:8084/myWebApp/analytics/res/b_mozilla/browserdom.js` which is a wrong path leading to this error **The requested resource is not available**.

What should I do to fix this error?

## Update: web.xml content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>ObieeBridge</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ObieeBridge</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ObieeBridge</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
            <param-value>10</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ObieeBridge</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ObieeBridge</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: please share web.xml file

Comment: How did you request this html file? I mean can you add code part where request is done?

Comment: @erhun The request is done via a Method in a JSF Managed Bean.
This method calls the distant web service (by a sequence of functions generated from a WSDL) which in turn returns a HTML code inserted and executed in the page calling the Managed Bean method.

I have provided all the details about my source code in this post
http://community.oracle.com/message/12598897

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Looks like you would need some URL rewriting. Why not hiding the wep application behind a reverse proxy like Apache HTTP server or nginx that can do all this rewriting for you ?

Comment: @SergeBallestaWhere does he do the url rewriting?@ML_TNit looks like you use an Oracle Framework and actually i can not track your request and response.